# "No such file or directory" when trying to install dependencies for a theme using "npm install"

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, themes, npm-install

I'm attempting to get a bootstrap based theme installed on Laravel. (The theme is called codeBase, it's a professional theme that I purchased on themeforest.net) I don't know if the problem I'm having is a problem with the theme or how I'm going about it but any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.  I have a support request in to the theme creator but I'm hoping to get the issue resolved tonight.

The theme includes a starter kit for Laravel which is the whole directory structure of a Laravel app with all of the theme's assets.

```
 .
    ├── app
    ├── bootstrap
    ├── config
    ├── database
    ├── public
    ├── resources
    ├── routes
    ├── storage
    ├── tests
    └── vendor
    .editorconfig
    .env
    .env.example
    .gitattributes
    .gitignore
    artisan
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    package.json
    package-lock.json
    phpunit.xml
    server.php
    webpack.mix.js
    yarn.lock
```

So you just copy these files and folders into your app's site folder on your server and then configure dependencies.  First you run composer:

```
composer install
```

This step completes without issues. Then you run npm:

```
npm install
```

This step fails the following error:

```
npm ERR! path 
/home/vagrant/code/evec/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io- 
client/package.json.424263211
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/home/vagrant/code/evec/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io- 
client/package.json.424263211'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-07-11T00_44_32_935Z-debug.log
```

I've done some research trying to resolve this and tried a few things but nothing seems to work. Most of what I found talked about clearing npm cache deleting the node_modules files and rerunning npm install.  There is a package.json and package-lock.json file already included. Could my problem be in there somewhere?

Could this have anything to do with my installation?  I'm running Laravel Homestead on a Vagrant box VM with barely anything changed from default install.  It seems to be running great other than the issue I'm currently having.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to solve the issue.

1. Delete node_modules folder manually.
2. Run npm install, if not working, try from vagrant, ssh vagrant, then go to the directory, and run npm install,

Comment: Now I get another very similar error:  npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/code/evec/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io-client/package.json.4004743014
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/evec/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io-client/package.json.4004743014'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-07-11T01_20_28_190Z-debug.log

Comment: This results in a different file name but similar error

Comment: Can you write the code where you are importing this package in your app.js file?

Comment: Just try it https://stackoverflow.com/a/65876422/4996461