# Error executing NPM INSTALL inside Homestead

Tags: laravel, npm, vagrant, npm-install, homestead

We are developing an app in Laravel, and we created a new project, we have an error when trying to run NPM INSTALL inside Homestead.

**We are using:

Vagrant 2.2.9
NPM 6.14.10
Node 12.20.0
The last homestead version
We tried:

Deleting node_modules
Deleting composer.json.lock
Cleaning cache
Reinstalling the virtual machine with the last version
And other stackoverflows.
But the solutions dont work.

And we can't run npm install. The error is: no such file or directory open 'home/vagrant/code/testing/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/package.json.3695679736' This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution, you need to: 1) install NFS in your local machine (sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server) 2) add  type: "nfs" in your Homestead.yaml after folder mapping 3) vagrant reload --provision and thats it. trying npm install now is working ok!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, you need to:

1. install NFS in your local machine (**sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server**) if u are using ubuntu, check how to do it in windows.
2. add **type: "nfs"** in your **Homestead.yaml** **after folder mapping**
3. **vagrant reload --provision**

And thats it. trying **npm install** now is working ok!